# LCD Base Address

Tags: c, microcontroller, iar

I'm coding in C with microcontrollers as part of degree and am struggling to find the base address of different components. The microcontroller I am using is the MSP430FR413x and I am currently trying to figure out the base address of the LCD screen so that I can display some text. Could anyone help me either with how to find the base address or what this base address is. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the datasheet yet?

Comment: That device has an LCD built-in?

Comment: @MartinJames It has an LCD controller peripheral, which one presumes is used in the OP's board to drive an LCD.

Comment: Yes I've checked the data sheet but I'm not 100% sure what a base address looks like. Yeah it has a built in LCD but I'm using a header file which is asking for the base address to initialise it and use different functions. How would I call the base address, is there a predefined function such as LCD_BASE?

Comment: Use TI provided headers! And read the family guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr4133.pdf) on page 70 they say, that the LCD driver's registers are at `0x600`. Is that what You are looking for?

Comment: Table 6-47. LCD Registers (Base Address: 0600h) on page 75 is even more interesting

Comment: I think this is it thanks very much! Could you possibly explain what the h at the end means. Sorry I am new to using microcontrollers

Comment: h = hexadecimal, 0600h = 0x0600